# How to select element with CSS when some items are nested before

Tags: css, css-selectors

In this scenario is it possible to use CSS selector to only select item 4?

```
<div>
  <div class="a">item 1</div>
  <div class="a">item 2</div>
  <div class="a">item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">item 4</div>
<div class="a">item 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this exact example, yes - though if you get much more complex it's going to get ugly and you'll probably need some (relatively simple) JavaScript.

In this example just use the [Adjacent Sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector in combination with the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class. This will target any `class="a"` that immediately follows a `div` that's *not* `class="a"`.

```css
div:not(.a) + .a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="a">item 1</div>
  <div class="a">item 2</div>
  <div class="a">item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="a">item 4</div>
<div class="a">item 5</div>
```